# Android List View - delete row button, delete selected button or delete from item click menu?

Tags: mobile, android, lists

Android List view activity with item rows. User needs to be able delete some rows.

I know standard way in Android is to use item click menu. But it's 2 clicks. Is it best way?

Comment: Another potential alternative is the swipe to delete (or swipe to reveal a delete button), iPhone style.

Comment: Don't implement iPhone behavior. Android users don't know them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It all comes down to how often the user will need to use delete function.

If it's very often, maybe consider adding a button to each list item.

If it's less often you should consider adding it to the items contextual menu (the long press menu). This is standard practice for most things.

I'm guessing when the user presses an item they will be taken to an activity with more information on it. You could add the delete button there or add it to the menu options on that activity (or both if really needed).

Comment: This is very good answer. It is always important to bear in mind how often any function is needed when designing the UI.

Comment: Long press menu is deprecated since Android 3.0, see http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html

Answer (score 7):

The interaction for deleting a list item needs to be complex enough to prevent accidents, yet not so difficult that it is a strain to delete multiple items.

For Android 3.x and 4.x, there is a recommendation by Google to use the "contextual action bar", whereby when an item is selected, you can add a delete icon to the action bar.  See:  http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html

An older, common interaction used on Android 2.x was to place the "Delete" action in a context menu activated by a long press on the list item.

One drawback for both these interfaces is that "Edit" and "Copy" or other common actions will often be near the "Delete" action, and so an irreversible "Delete" may require some additional form of confirmation input to prevent accidents.  (Contrast this with the iPhonesque "swipe to reveal a delete button", which, by being unique and two steps, needs no confirmation.)

See Google's 2.x SMS "Messaging" app as an Android example:  Deleting a item requires a long press, the selection of "Delete" from a crowded context menu, and then final confirmation of the delete in an alert dialog.

Comment: Apple has patented using an "Edit" button on a list that reveals "Delete" buttons: http://www.patentlyapple.com/patently-apple/2012/01/apple-wins-an-original-iphone-patent-for-editing-lists-and-more.html

Is "swipe-to-reveal-delete" also patented?

Comment: This is answer should be accepted. It reflects the current design patterns. Deletion in a list is contextual and should be implemented with either a CAM (in which case multiple deletion can be supported) or a long-press options modal, depending on the Android version. I would add that there are also confirmation patterns for destructive action. See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/confirming-acknowledging.html, namely the Gmail deletion example. See http://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/undobar for an implementation.