# Removing a listview cell in Android - UI Pattern?

Tags: android, deletion

I come from an iOS background and so I'm not too familiar with how things work on Android. What I need to do is something to the equivalent of "Slide to remove" feature that is normally used to remove `UITableView` cells on iOS.

Here're some screenshots as to how this is done on iOS:

[image]

[image]

This action on iOS is triggered either by having a "Edit" or a "Delete" button which puts the `UITableView` in an edit mode or by sliding your finger across a row. Is there an equivalent pattern for ListViews in Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android List View - delete row button, delete selected button or delete from item click menu](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/202/android-list-view-delete-row-button-delete-selected-button-or-delete-from-item). You may want to take a look at that question and see if it addresses what you're asking about.

Comment: Whoops, thanks. That works for me :). Will someone close this? Or if you can post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Rain re-post your message as an answer as it is the answer. We can vote to close but for completeness sake we should post the answer.

Comment: @jonshariat Sure thing. I wasn't sure what the generally accepted practice was here- in that case.

Comment: @Rain Ya no problem just wanted you to get your credit for a great answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Android List View - delete row button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/202/android-list-view-delete-row-button-delete-selected-button-or-delete-from-item), delete selected button or delete from item click menu. You may want to take a look at that question and see if it addresses what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

There's another pattern that is used frequently in Android lists that can offer the same functionality. It is called quick actions. If you only need to remove an item it's not the right pattern to use but if you need to add more actions you might want to consider using it:
http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/03/ui-design-pattern-quick-actions.html